# Como pegar retorno Json do site Hgbrasil Weather em minha aplicação Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Como faço para pegar os valores disponibilizados no formato Json em minha aplicação Xamarin.

**O código abaixo não esta retornando nada.**

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView txtv1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        txtv1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtResposta);

        OlaRestAsync();//Chamada
    }

    private async Task OlaRestAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://api.hgbrasil.com/weather/?format=json&city_name=Ribeir%C3%A3o%20Preto&key=2857c531");
        var dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HgWeather>(json);

        txtv1.Text = dados.results.description;
    }
}
```

**Classes**

```
public class HgWeather
{
    public string by { get; set; }
    public bool valid_key { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
    public float execution_time { get; set; }
    public bool from_cache { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public int temp { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string condition_code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string currently { get; set; }
    public string cid { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string img_id { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
    public string wind_speedy { get; set; }
    public string sunrise { get; set; }
    public string sunset { get; set; }
    public string condition_slug { get; set; }
    public string city_name { get; set; }
    public Forecast[] forecast { get; set; }
}

public class Forecast
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string weekday { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
    public string min { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Não ha problemas nenhum com o código acima, mas sim o problema esta com a api do site hgbrasil.com que deve ter algum problema, que não sei qual é. **Gostaria muito que o hgbrasil.com funcionasse pois não me preocuparia com traduções. Mas fazer o que.** Tentando com outra url o código funcionou perfeitamente. `var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://viacep.com.br/ws/29400000/json/");` Funcionou perfeitamente também com os sites De meteorologia:
openweathermap.org De notícias
newsapi.org

Comment: Para que as perguntas possam ser tratadas dentro do escopo deste site é importante sempre fornecer um [mcve] do problema que não dependa de nenhuma API externa (por exemplo, simulando dados já baixados de forma que não seja necessário ninguém da comunidade consultar links, e que a pergunta continue válida se a API mudar). Quando for problema de entendimento/funcionamento da API e não do algoritmo ou do funcionamento da sua parte do código, já seria o caso de consultar o suporte do fornecedor da API diretamente. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.